# Increase net size and change shape of wireframe modifier

Tags: modifiers, wireframe

I'm trying to replicate [this](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2704299) process in Blender.
So far, I found a 3D model and tried to apply a wireframe modifier:

[image]

What I'm not able to do yet:

1. increase the net size (thickness will increase the width of the wires, decimate or subdivision make a mess...)
2. change the net shape from rectangular to an arbitrary one (ideally to Voronoi, but if it is too complex, I can live with any other irregular shape)

I'm using Blender 4.0.0 alpha, but I also have Blender 3.5.1.

Comment: Hello, what do you mean by "increase the net size"? As for the shape, giving a Subdivision Surface will round the shapes if this is what you want

Comment: @moonboots: i think he wants just "bigger" holes but then he has to use a second model with another topology, if he wants to use the wireframe modifier....a shader might be the better solution here

Comment: @Chris, exactly. If my approach is not correct, please feel free to propose another solution!